# How to remove multiple spaces between words in Python, without the leading spaces

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing a simple Sublime Text plugin to trim extra, unnecessary, spaces between words but without touching the leading spaces not to mess up Python formatting.

I have:

```
[spaces*******are********here]if****not***regions***and**default_to_all:
```

and want to get:

```
[spaces***are***still****here]if not regions and default_to_all:
```

Thinking about

```
regions = view.find_all('\w\s{2,}\w')
view.erase(edit, region)
```

but it cuts out the first and the last letter too.

Comment: Can you add an example of a string that my answer won't catch?  I'm slightly confused about what you need exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-matching leading spaces implies you want to match multiple spaces following a non-space character (and replace it with single space), so you can replace `(?<=\S) +(?=\S)` with single space "".

Explanation:

```
(?<=\S) +(?=\S)
(?<=              Positive look-behind, which means preceded by...
    \S                non-space character
      )           end of look-behind group
        +         more than 1 space
         (?=\S)   Positive look-ahead, which means followed by...
                      non-space character
                  end of look-ahead group
```

That should be straight-forward to understand.  You may need to tweak it a bit for trailing space handling though.

See "[regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/r/WpvWl3/2)" for more information.

However, just as a side note regarding your intention:
This is not going to be a reliable way to reformat code.  Apart from leading spaces, there are still many cases of multiple-spaces that are significant.  The most obvious one is spaces within string literal.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I avoid deleting the first character? Please see the picture  below.

Comment: don't understand what you meant by deleting first character.  Create a regex101 example to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Please check this out: https://regex101.com/r/5d1cCY/1 Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderPaulWansiedler don't understand what you are trying to do.  It is simply doing what you are looking for: matching "a non-hash character followed by bunch of spaces"

Comment: I want only the spaces to be removed. As you see, sometimes a non space character BEFORE the spaces is being removed too. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @AlexanderPaulWansiedler it is just different from what you originally asked for in your original question, and the regex you are using is different too.  Please be clear on what you are trying to do.  We are not supposed to keep guessing your need.

Comment: Please read the first sentence in my question. I specifically asked about deleting only the spaces. Current regexp ```[^#](?<=\S)( {2,})(?=\S)``` also deletes randomly nonspace character before the spaces. Please check the link I posted. There you can see what I mean.

Comment: As I said before: the example you provided is different from what you originally asked, and regex you used in the example is different from the answer.

Comment: Please tell me should I create a new post?

Comment: You may.  However I would recommend you to really understand the original answer and understand how it works.  If you really understand this answer, and if my guess on what you were doing is correct, the solution just require a slight tweak.

Comment: I read the documentation, but I still cant figure out how to prevent a random cutting of some letters =(

Comment: There is no random cutting. Your regex means matching “a non-# char, followed by spaces.” That non-# char is part of the match hence it will be replaced. The whole reason of using lookahead and look behind group in my answer is to avoid something to be part of match.

Comment: Thank you! Tell please, how can I prevent that non-# char from being cut with spaces?

Comment: That's why I kept saying you should try to understand the original answer.  Try to understand the effect of lookaround groups in regex

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'( *[\S]*)(?: +)(\n)?')
>>> s = '       if   not regions    and  default_to_all:\n     foo'
>>> r.sub(' ', s)
   if not regions and default_to_all:
 foo
```

Comment: sorry, not gonna work. As I said leading spaces in every line should be kept. (r'\s+') is gonna kill all of them.

Comment: @Alexander so leading spaces after a newline character (ie `\n`) should be preserved?

Comment: @Alexander what's wrong with my new pattern?  It preserves all spaces at the beginning, and all spaces after any newline?

Comment: {2,}$ implies spaces before the end of the line, but what about spaces between words?

Comment: @Alexander sorry I can't believe I posted that last one.  I added another update.

Comment: Sorry, not gonna work. : was just for an example. It has to matches spaces between words only.